# How to use google adsense and google analytics for my site

Tags: google-analytics, website-design, google-adsense

Hi i've got a site serving content to Brazil http://montao.com.br via google app engine getting comfortable with updating it with new function now also adding google adsense and analytics to the site. Now I want to know if you can follow the link to maybe give me some good advice how to use adsense and analytics since adding these tools is adding script that could slow down the pages' load times.

Thank you

Comment: I was able to load your web page. I noticed that you had moved the Google stuff to the bottom. That's a good piece of advice from Christofian!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the **google analytics** code at the bottom (the page will load faster). Other than that, you're good to go.

Comment: NOTE: you can put the **adsense** code anywhere you want. However, you should put the **analytics** code at the bottom, to make the page load faster.